# Segmentation fault error while freeing the memory

Tags: c

I tried to make a self-made program for lists. So, I created some basic stuff like creating the list, adding new nodes, showing them, and deleting all the existing nodes in the list.

However, when I put in my list more than 27 elements, it throws me a segmentation fault error while freeing the memory. By the way, when I add like 26 or smaller number of them, it works great. Maybe stack is overflowed or something like that, I really have no idea.

P.S don't tell me that I`m developing a bike, in this way, making something by myself first, I understand things better:)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct node{
    struct node * next;
    int value;
} node;

int addNode(int position,int value, node ** head,int * size){
    int i = 2;
    node * curNode = *head;
    if(position > *size) return;
    while(i <= *size){
        if(position == 1){
            node * adress = *head;
            *head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
            (*head)->next = adress;
            (*head)->value = value;
            break;
        }

        else if(i == position){
            node * adress = curNode->next;
            curNode->next = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
            curNode = curNode->next;
            curNode->next = adress;
            curNode->value = value;
            break;
        }
        else{
            curNode = curNode->next;            
            ++i;            
        }       
    }   
    ++(*size);      
    return;     
}

void showList(node * head, int size){
    int i; node * currentNode = head;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        printf(" %d , next adress: %p |\n", currentNode->value, currentNode->next);
        currentNode = currentNode->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void cleanList(node * head, int size){
    int i;
    node * curNode = head; node * nextToDelete = NULL;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        nextToDelete = curNode->next;
        free(curNode);
        curNode = nextToDelete;
    }
}

int main() {
    node * head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*)); //saving head adress to know where the list starts
    head->value = 1; //set head value as "1"    
    int i, size;    
    node * currentNode = head; //pointer which points to a current node     
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i){         
        node * adress = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*)); //variable which saves new node`s adress
        currentNode->next = adress; //set this new nod`s adress to previous node`s "next" parametr      
        currentNode = adress; //set new node`s adress to a current node 
        currentNode->value = i+2; ///set value for this node    
    }   
    size = 6;       
    addNode(2, 15, &head, &size);  
    showList(head, size);
    showList(head, size);  
    cleanList(head, size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the empty lines from the code snippet, I think they are there by mistake. `int i = 2;` - why `2`?

Comment: There is no use to set it as 1, becouse it is a special  case for it. So, we better start from 2

Comment: But if you start with `2`, then `position == i`. So you change the head of the list. Without changing the head. And why `i <= *size` - you index your list starting from one or from zero?

Comment: nope, i add new element between the head and the next element

Comment: Don't you get errors when compiling the code? How do you `return;` from a `int addNode` - function that returns an `int`? Then your compiler is very bad, you should _at least_ get a warning/notice or anything. You don't return anything from a function retuning an `int`. I compiled the code and run the code and it works. Did I do something wrong? What should I do to make it fail? Do `addNode(2, 100, ...` ? Please post the code that actually recreates the problem you are seeing.

Comment: i have no errors

Comment: try add like 50 nodes

Comment: Then your compiler tells you that: `./1.c: In function ‘addNode’:
./1.c:12:26: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
   12 |     if(position > *size) return;
      |                          ^~~~~~
./1.c:9:5: note: declared here
    9 | int addNode(int position,int value, node ** head,int * size){
      |     ^~~~~~~
./1.c:36:5: warning: ‘return’ with no value, in function returning non-void
   36 |     return;
      |     ^~~~~~
./1.c:9:5: note: declared here
    9 | int addNode(int position,int value, node ** head,int * size){
      |     ^~~~~~~`

Comment: i have no warnings, but i gonna fix it anyway, i mean return something

Comment: I strongly believe [that's not possible](https://godbolt.org/z/_V9Ac3). On top of that, I have looped your `addNode` function 120 times [on gobolt](https://godbolt.org/z/vm3v-A) and your code works just fine (executed without segmentation fault). The sources of the code are available under the links on godbolt.org. I have also executed the code on my machine - valgrind tells me `All heap blocks were freed`. Please post actually the code that recreates the problem you are seeing.

Comment: hmm, it is stack though?

Comment: Oh, in real tI got a SIGTRAP problem. When i run my debugger, it point me to this line of code: cleanList(head, size);

Comment: @KamilCuk IMHO, that depends on the standard version you compile in. I think, the C standard used to allow functions declared with a return value to not return a value, causing undefined behaviour if the value was evaluated nevertheless. I am not proficient with the ancient stuff, but at least the C11 standard mentions under "7 Major changes in the second edition included:" : "- return without expression not permitted in function that returns a value..." indicating that this *used* to be allowed.  So if you compile in C89, I would not be surprised if that return thingy was valid.

Comment: I have the old standart then. I still must write "int i" out of the loop and only after doing that use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allocating memory incorrectly.

Notice these lines:

```
*head = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

and

```
curNode->next = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node*));
```

You are allocating memory for a pointer to `struct node` instead of the actual struct.
Notice the `sizeof` function - you pass it the wrong parameter!

Your structure contains an `int` and a pointer. Those are usually the same size.
But you only allocate memory for a pointer, so, you allocate half the structure.

This will cause you to call `free` on an invalid address at some point.
It is a miracle your program only crashed during `free` operation, it should have crashed much sooner.

Comment: I should change it like node * adress = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));?

Comment: @user11729819 Yes exactly.

Comment: It works now, but could anybody check whethet all the heap blocks were freed? I have no valgrind:(

Comment: In C you do not have to cast the return from `malloc`, so those just add clutter: just assign the `void *` pointer where you want to store it.

Comment: You mean write like: node * adress = (void*) malloc(...); ?

Comment: @user11729819 He means `node * adress = malloc(sizeof(node));` will work fine.